# Why does my console window close before my program has finished?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    cout << "Enter you name here: " << flush; //prints Enter your name here:

    string input;
    cin >> input;
    cout << "Is this correct?: " << input << endl; //asks user Is this correct?: 
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

After I run the application, I enter in my name then it automatically closes without going to the next statement.

Comment: The console running your program closes?

Comment: When i put in my name the console closes

Comment: Do you use/hit breakpoints?

Comment: Not that it should make much difference, but are we talking input of "Jaden" or "Jaden Zayas"? `cin >> input;` will stop reaing after it finds whitespace, leaving plenty of characters in the stream to trigger `cin.get();` and exit.

Comment: I currently do not use breakpoints

Comment: Off topic: test the result of your reads to make sure they succeeded. And look into breakpoints and the debugger in general. The time they can save you is astronomical.

Comment: Probably it does go to the next statement and display the thing, but you didn't notice because the window closed too quickly afterwards

Answer (score 6):

```
 cin >> input;
```

Here you entered your name, "Jaden", and pressed the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Therefore, the entered input consists of: "Jaden" and `'\n'` which is six characters.

The `>>` operator reads "Jaden", places it in `input`, and leaves `'\n'` unread, in `std::cin`.

```
 cin.get();
```

And this reads the `'\n'` character, from `std::cin`, and your program immediately ends, and terminates.

Comment: Is this problem limited to visual studio ? because this code compiled and runs without any problem in `code blocks`.

Comment: @Yousaf this is law everywhere the C++ Standard is followed. Visual Studio's console closes immediately on program completion making the error obvious. I can't speak for Code::Blocks, but it may keep the console around.

Comment: Yes but how do you fix this problem?

Comment: If your intent is to read an entire line of text from `std::cin`, use `std::getline()` instead of the `>>` operator. That's what it's there for.